# How to control order of bean init-method invocation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, initialization, javabeans

Suppose I have bean, which init-method or constructor should be called after init-method of another bean. Is it possible?

Answer (score 14):

Use `depends-on` attribute in spring context XML file:

```
<bean id="beanOne" class="ExampleBean" depends-on="manager">
  <property name="manager"><ref local="manager"/></property>
</bean>
```

or `@DependsOn` annotation on bean if you are using annotations.

Comment: @fasttooth, good question. I do not know exact answer. It *probably* works because as far as I know spring invokes all post construct methods after wiring, so probably it uses the same order as used for wiring. But  I am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`@DependsOn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/DependsOn.html) annotation or depends-on attribute if you're using xml configuration.

Comment: Does spring also honor the `javax.ejb.DependsOn` annotation? The documentation for the corresponding spring annotation can be found at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use de `depends-on` attribute on your second bean.

Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson