# Hibernate collection is not associated with any session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have found several questions and answers with regard to this issue on SO, but they all seem to cover one major cause of the problem: fetching a collection outside of a transaction or within another transaction.  But in my case, I am fetching within the same transaction when fetching a parent object and collection.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class IntegrationServiceImpl implements IntegrationService {
@Override
    public Integration getIntegrationByIdFetchBackendParameters(Long integrationId) {
        Integration integration = integrationDao.get(integrationId);
        //not all integrations have to have backend.
        if (integration.getBackend() != null) {
            Hibernate.initialize(integration.getBackend().getBackendParameters());
        }
        return integration;
    }
...
```

But when it comes to Hibernate.initialize this branch in  org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection
is executed

```
if ( session == null ) {
                throw new HibernateException( "collection is not associated with any session" );
            }
```

I cant see why `session` is `null`. Would someone explain this and suggest a solution?

**EDIT 1 - Full stack trace**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:676)
        at org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:77)
        at com.dhl.finFw.service.IntegrationServiceImpl.getIntegrationByIdFetchBackendParameters(IntegrationServiceImpl.java:169)
        at com.dhl.finFw.web.integration.IntegrationOverviewManagedBean.loadIntegration(IntegrationOverviewManagedBean.java:59)
        at com.dhl.finFw.web.integration.AbstractIntegrationManagedBean.initCommonFields(AbstractIntegrationManagedBean.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at com.dhl.finFw.spring.scope.ViewScope.get(ViewScope.java:30)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:56)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:68)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:161)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:166)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:320)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:379)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:358)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:120)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:179)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:320)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:379)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:358)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:164)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:870)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.dhl.finFw.web.filter.FileNotFoundFilter.doFilter(FileNotFoundFilter.java:40)
        at com.dhl.finFw.web.filter.FileNotFoundFilter.doFilter(FileNotFoundFilter.java:35)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**Edit 2 - configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
          class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
        <property name="passwordSysPropertyName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationEncryptor"
          class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>${finFw.config.location}finFwUI.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:dateTime.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dhl.finFw"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="FINFW"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${finFwUI.orm.generateDdl:false}"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="${finFwUI.orm.showSql:false}"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${finFwUI.orm.dialect}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="com.dhl.finFw.spring.scope.ViewScope"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
        <property name="attributes">
            <map>
                <entry key="finFwUIEnvironment" value="${finFwUI.environment}" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="eventListenerBean" class="com.dhl.finFw.spring.FinFwApplicationListener" />

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>FinFwUI</display-name>
    <description>Financial Framework Configuration</description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.dhl.finFw.web.FileServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Location of the Log4J config file, for initialization and refresh checks.
        Applied by Log4jConfigListener. The variable is replaced with System property 
        at runtime. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>${finFw.config.location}log4j-finFwUI.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Application version. The variable is replaced during Maven build. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>applicationVersion</param-name>
        <param-value>${applicationVersion}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>dhl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- possible values: Development, Production, SystemTest, UnitTest The 
        variable is replaced during Maven build or set as System property during 
        development. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>${finFwUI.jsf.stage}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring application context config locations -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:com/dhl/finFw/finFwUI-core.xml
            classpath:com/dhl/finFw/finFwUI-dataSource.xml
            classpath:com/dhl/finFw/finFwUI-security.xml
            classpath:com/dhl/finFw/finFwUI-forms.xml
            classpath:com/dhl/finFw/finFwUI-audit.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- Configures Log4J for this web app. As this context specifies a context-param
        "log4jConfigLocation", its file path is used to load the Log4J configuration. -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Starts Spring application context. The parent one. The web context 
        is started by Dispatcher servlet. -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/file/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/protected/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>fileNotFoundFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.dhl.finFw.web.filter.FileNotFoundFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>browserCacheControlFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.dhl.finFw.web.filter.BrowserCacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>fileNotFoundFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>browserCacheControlFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/protected/integration/subscriptionScheduler.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException</exception-type>
        <location>/pages/public/error/accessDenied.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/pages/public/error/internal.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/pages/public/error/internal.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/pages/public/error/notFound.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/pages/public/error/accessDenied.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**ViewScope.java**

```
public class ViewScope implements Scope {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static final String VIEW_SCOPE_CALLBACKS = "viewScope.callbacks";

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
        Map<String, Object> viewMap = getViewMap();
        Object instance = viewMap.get(name);
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = objectFactory.getObject();
            synchronized (viewMap) {
                viewMap.put(name, instance);
                logger.debug("Bean '{}' has been put to ViewScope.", instance);
            }
        } else {
            logger.debug("Going to return an existing bean '{}'", instance);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    @Override
    public Object remove(String name) {
        Object instance = getViewMap().remove(name);
        if (instance != null) {
            Map<String, Runnable> callbacks = (Map<String, Runnable>) getViewMap().get(VIEW_SCOPE_CALLBACKS);
            if (callbacks != null) {
                callbacks.remove(name);
                logger.debug("Bean '{}' has been removed.", instance);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable runnable) {
        Map<String, Runnable> callbacks = (Map<String, Runnable>) getViewMap().get(VIEW_SCOPE_CALLBACKS);
        if (callbacks != null) {
            callbacks.put(name, runnable);
            logger.debug("Registered callback for '{}'", name);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject(String name) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesRequestAttributes facesRequestAttributes = new FacesRequestAttributes(facesContext);
        return facesRequestAttributes.resolveReference(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesRequestAttributes facesRequestAttributes = new FacesRequestAttributes(facesContext);
        return facesRequestAttributes.getSessionId() + "-" + facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getViewMap() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add full stacktrace...

Comment: I have added full stack trace. See edit.

Comment: The stacktrace indicates that there is no transaction going on. Basically your `@Transactional` isn't doing anything. Post your configuration (including web.xml)

Comment: I have added web.xml and core configuration of my app.

Comment: Judging from the configuration and stacktrace your custom `ViewScope` is doing something. Can you post that code and also the code that calls the `getIntegrationByIdFetchBackendParameters` method.

Comment: ViewScope is copy/pasted from here http://www.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/
And this method is called from one line method from managed bean which is view scoped  (with ViewScope)
`integration = integrationService.getIntegrationByIdFetchBackendParameters(integrationId);`

Comment: Link gives an error and can you post the whole method instead of a single line...

Comment: It is this method 
`protected void loadIntegration() {
        integration = integrationService.getIntegrationByIdFetchBackendParameters(integrationId);
    }` which is called from init method with @PostConstruct.
I have added ViewScope class to the post.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this issue just putting `@Transactional` at top of the method.

Comment: Just to add an important detail: the `@Transactional` annotation should be placed high enough in your call hierarchy. Putting it on top of a low-level method where you eventually use such a proxied property, won't fix anything. It should be placed on a method from where your object is loaded and from where that other method that needs the property is called. Visualising these calls as a tree, your `@Transactional` annotation should be at the root (but no higher than necessary either, of course).

Answer (score 8):

To prevent a `LazyLoadingException` in my application, I use a helper method that first merges the entity back to the session and then initializes the requested collections. It recently turned out, that sometimes it still suffers from the "collection is not associated with any session" issue despite the session seems to be open and looks fine overall. It's hard for me to say what is the cause of such behavior, but still I found a remedy against it. Try to refresh the entity state before fetching the lazy collection using `session.refresh(entity)`. This will cause Hibernate to reload your entity from the DB. After doing this, your current session will let you to load your collections smoothly with `Hibernate.initialize()`.

Comment: Your problem with "collection not associated with any session" is probably persisting because you have made an error with your helper method that merges the entity back into the session. I've found it's really easy to accidentally still be using a handle on the old (unmerged) entity, which of course will upset Hibernate.

Comment: @Lisa what do you mean by "error with helper method that merges"? If you are using the native utility library to initialize and loaded an object with proxy and trying to initialize/unproxy it, seems like a) going back to the DB is redundant b) core libraries should have associated the session?

Answer (score 2):

As @Zmicier Zaleznicenka has pointed out, this exception message may have nothing to do with the Session. 
We have also encountered this problem, but the root cause was the entity primary key setting defined in the mapping file was incorrect. For example, in the following code, the database column "Foo_SK" is not the unique identifier of the table.

```
Id(x => x.Id, "Foo_SK").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

In our case, we have no control over the database schema. Therefore, we fixed the problem by using composite key mapping.

[Please check the other post for the same issue.](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1006350&view=next)

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem however the problem for me was that i wasnt configuring the transactional management in my config file so :

add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to java Config file
or
add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to xml config file

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue just putting `@Transactional` at top of the method.
And also get the class by its id like this:

```
Test s=get(test.getId())
```

Comment: Hi Nitheesh, welcome to SO. Consider adding details on how this solution solves the issue. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you call this in your `init` method of `AbstractIntegrationManagedBean`.

You have to make sure that hibernate gets set up properly before that point.

Most likely your configuration does not reflect that and you assume hibernate to be already there, although there is no guarantee for that.

See this question for more details: [How to control order of bean init-method invocation in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378962/how-to-control-order-of-bean-init-method-invocation-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Based on **Zmicier Zaleznicenka** answer:

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
session.refresh(myObject);
Hibernate.initialize(myObject.getAnotherObject());
```

Session Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151834/6909832